# Facing issues with threads in using @Async

Tags: multithreading, spring, asynchronous

I have a requirement in a webservice, a database call which will updates some info in a table. 
And expectation is nearly 20k clients needs to be supported to hit this webservice within span of seconds.

For this purpose, i used @Async annotation in Spring 3 to serve this purpose on the service call along with below config.

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"/>     
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean">
      <property name="corePoolSize" value="5000" />
      <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10000" />
      <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="5000" />
</bean>
```

Till 2000 clients are only served and not more than that on a 4GB RAM capacity testing machine.

Tried below option as well.. but no luck

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"/>     
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean">
      <property name="corePoolSize" value="3000" />
      <property name="maxPoolSize" value="15000" />
      <property name="queueCapacity" value="9000" />
      <!-- <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="5000" /> -->
      <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Need your help in resolving this issue.

Pasting service class details as requested:

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
@Async
public void processAndSave(String tLine) {
    ...
    ...
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        try {
            String token =st.nextToken().trim();
            map = StringUtil.fetchMapFrom(token);
            if (isNotEmptyMap(map) && (map.size() == InfoHeaders.values().length)) {
                tList.add(prepareTInfo(map));
            } else {
                tErrorList.add(prepareTErrorInfo(token,map));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("processAndSave:Unable to process and save", e);
        }
    }

    if(tList!=null && tList.size()>0){
        mongoTemplate.insert(tList,TInfo.class);
    }

    if(tErrorList!=null && tErrorList.size()>0){
        mongoTemplate.insert(tErrorList,TErrorInfo.class);
    }
}


public TInfo prepareTInfo(Map<String, String> tlMap) {
    TInfo tcInfo = null;
    try {
        if (isNotEmptyMap(tlMap)) {
            tcInfo = new TInfo();
            tcInfo.setActivityId(tlMap.get(String.valueOf(InfoHeaders.A)));
            tcInfo.setBattVal(tlMap.get(String.valueOf(InfoHeaders.B)));
            tcInfo.setLocVal(tlMap.get(String.valueOf(InfoHeaders.L)));
            tcInfo.setDateTime(tlMap.get(String.valueOf(InfoHeaders.T)));
            tcInfo.setTId(tlMap.get(String.valueOf(InfoHeaders.ID)));
            tcInfo.setTempVal(tlMap.get(String.valueOf(InfoHeaders.D)));
            tcInfo.setCreatedDate(new Date());
            tcInfo.setIsDataPushed(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
    return tcInfo;
}

public TErrorInfo prepareTErrorInfo(String errorTLine,Map<String, String> map) {
    TErrorInfo tceInfo = null;
    try {
        tceInfo = new TErrorInfo();
        tceInfo.setErrorTMsg(errorTLine);
        tceInfo.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        tceInfo.setIsDataPushed(0);
        tceInfo.setTId(map.get(String.valueOf(InfoHeaders.ID)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
    return tceInfo;
}
```

The data is being inserted into db using mongoTemplate.

Please suggest me further.

Comment: please post your service class and also exception stack trace; if any.

Comment: There is no exception or stack trace. QA are testing with JMeter to initiating 2500 client requests to invoke the service and the method in service is calling hibernate save which is saving the changes.

Comment: @JavaBond I have updated the service class details as well. Please suggest me further.

Comment: There is no mention about JVM memory configuration. Even if you have machine with 4GB capacity, you need to change arguments to utilize it.